# Problem connecting local POSTGIS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm trying to connect to local POSTGIS database using QGIS.
I'm using the POSTGIS Tutorial form Buondless (rif. http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/index.html).

The context is the following:

- Windows 7
- "POSTGIS="2.1.1 r12113" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel.
    4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"
- QGIS 2.0.1

I can define the db, adding data from a shapefile and all seems work fine when I'm in pgAdmin.

When I Try to connect the postgis database from QGIS no connection works.

Here you are the configuration I'm using

[image: Data base POSTGIS configuration]
[image: QGIS connection parameters]

The error is a generic "Check parameter and retry".

I've noted that if I don't set username and password the error is

```
FATAL: role "520" does not exist.
```

`520` is my network username in my Company. ??????

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell QGIS that the database server is on running localhost. Try making Host = 'localhost'.

Also you are trying to connect to the postgres maintenance db. Try creating a spatial database using the postgis template, then try connecting to that.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name TEMPLATE = template_postgis_20;
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I've tried to use Host= localhost but it doesn't work. I've tried also using the IP address but it doesn't work ...... :-)

Comment: " ......you are trying to connect to the postgres maintenance db. ...." This is the key!!!! I'm NOT using the right name for my spatial db: the name is "nyc"

Comment: Thank you very much Matt and sorry for my stupid question ..... :-)